# Typescript complex Generics with Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-tsx

I was asking this question with a more complex version of this basic concept
Rel: [Can Generic JSX.Elements work in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958773/can-generic-jsx-elements-work-in-typescript)

I narrowed it down to the core Elements:

This is `Object A` that takes parameters from `TypeA`

```
type TypeA = {
  label: string
  value: number
}
const ObjA = ({ label, value }:TypeA) => {
  return <div>
    <div>Label: {label}</div>
    <div>Value: {value}</div>
  </div>
}
```

This is `Object B` that takes parameters from `TypeB`

```
type TypeB = {
  label: string
  value: string
  bool: boolean
}
const ObjB = ({ label, value, bool }:TypeB) => {
  return <div>
    <div>Label: {label}</div>
    {bool && <div>Value: {value}</div>}
  </div>
}
```

Now I collect this ComponentGroup inside an array and create a Type out of this Array:

```
const ComponentCollection = [
  ObjA,
  ObjB
] as const
type Components = typeof ComponentCollection[number]
```

Then I create a generic component:

```
interface GenericProps<T extends Components> {
  Component: T
  title: string
}
const Generic = <T extends Components,>({ Component, title, ...props }:GenericProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{title}</label>
      <Component {...props}/>
  </div>
  )
}
```

At last I can call the generic component as follows:

```
<Generic Component={ObjA} title={'Usage A'}           label={'Object A'} value={'String A'}/>
<Generic Component={ObjB} title={'Usage B no Bool'}   label={'Object B'} value={0}/>
<Generic Component={ObjB} title={'Usage B with Bool'} label={'Object B'} value={0} bool/>
```

Altough it works really well in JavaScript, I messed something up with the typing.

I setup one TS-Playground and one Codepen:
TS-Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WvVarW
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Cascade8/pen/eYezGVV

### Goal:

1. Convert this code above in correct TypeScript code
2. Compile without any TS-Errors or `/@ts-ignore`
3. Make IntelliSense work, so if you type `<Generic Component={ObjA} ...` it shows the available type attributes for this Object. In this case: `label={string: } value={string: }`

### What i don't want:

1. Usage of classes or the old function syntax as our EsLint requires us to use an Arrow-Function if possible.
2. Passing the Objects as a Child.
   I know this works, but it is not the prefered solution as the main Project has a lot of groups like this that get rendered like this.
   And why shouldn't something work in TypeScript that works very simple in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Following the way you've constructed your types, you can do it using the definition of your generic inside `GenericProps`

(Note, I have bundled the props into a new `props` prop, as this should avoid name collisions should you have naming collisions)

```
import React from 'React'

type TypeA = {
  label: string
  value: number
}
const ObjA = ({ label, value }:TypeA) => {
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <label>{value}</label>
  </div>
}
type TypeB = {
  label: string
  value: string
  bool: boolean
}
const ObjB = ({ label, value, bool }:TypeB) => {
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    {bool && <label>{value}</label>}
  </div>
}

type Components = typeof ObjA | typeof ObjB;

interface GenericProps<T extends (...args: any) => any> {
  Component: T
  title: string
  props: Parameters<T>[0]
}

const Generic = <T extends Components,>({ Component, title, props }:GenericProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{title}</label>
      <Component {...props as any}/>
    </div>
  )
}
const Usage = () => {
  return <Generic Component={ObjA} title={'Usage'} props={{label: 'ObjectA'}}/>
}
export default Generic
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the closest thing to achieve it. I recreated it in TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WyblKw Sadly there still is an Error inside the Component part

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's because inside `Generic` the type of props isn't specified as matching the entry in `Components`, that's done inside `GenericProps`. You could assert the type in the line that you use them though.

You could just cast to `as any` inside there. It doesn't affect the types inside `Generic`

Comment: @Cascade_Ho, call Component as a normal function rather than via JSX, i.e., `Component(props)` rather than `<Component {...props}/>`.  That will avoid the LibraryManagedAttributes that are causing your issue, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do without any kind of type assertions.
Consider this exmaple:

```js
import React, { FC, } from 'react'

type Type = {
  label: string;
  value: string | number
}

type TypeA = {
  label: string
  value: number
}

type FixSubtyping<T> = Omit<T, 'title'>

const ObjA = ({ label, value }: FixSubtyping<TypeA>) => {
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <label>{value}</label>
  </div>
}

type TypeB = {
  label: string
  value: string
  bool: boolean
}

const ObjB = ({ label, value, bool }: FixSubtyping<TypeB>) => {
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    {bool && <label>{value}</label>}
  </div>
}


type Props<T> = T & {
  title: string
}


const withTitle = <T extends Type>(Component: FC<FixSubtyping<Props<T>>>) =>
  ({ title, ...props }: Props<T>) => (
    <div>
      <label>{title}</label>
      <Component {...props} />
    </div>
  )

const GenericA = withTitle(ObjA)
const GenericB = withTitle(ObjB)

const jsxA = <GenericA title={'Usage'} label={'A'} value={42} /> // // ok

const jsxB = <GenericB title={'Usage'} label={'A'} value={'str'} bool={true} /> // // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nab49m)

This error occurs because `props` is infered as `Omit<T,'title'>` so we should assure TS that Component `props` is compatible with `Omit<T,'title'>`

However there is a drawback, you need to update props type in other components. If it is not an option, I think the best approach would be to overload your `Generic` function:

```js
import React, { FC, } from 'react'

type TypeA = {
  label: string
  value: number
}

type FixSubtyping<T> = Omit<T, 'title'>

const ObjA = ({ label, value }: TypeA) => {
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <label>{value}</label>
  </div>
}

type TypeB = {
  label: string
  value: string
  bool: boolean
}

const ObjB = ({ label, value, bool }: TypeB) => {
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    {bool && <label>{value}</label>}
  </div>
}


type Props<T> = T & {
  Component: FC<T>,
  title: string
}


function Generic<T,>(props: Props<T>): JSX.Element
function Generic({ Component, title, ...props }: Props<unknown>) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{title}</label>
      <Component {...props} />
    </div>
  )
}

const jsxA = <Generic Component={ObjA} title={'Usage'} label={'A'} value={42} /> // // ok

const jsxB = <Generic Component={ObjB} title={'Usage'} label={'A'} value={'str'} bool={true} /> // // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzAa4m)

Comment: Ty for your Solution. Is this Possible to do this with an Arrow Function ? I somehow can't get it to work

Comment: @Cascade_Ho unfortunately no, it should infer `T` generic parameter

Comment: Okay. Well, EsLint ignore > @ts-ignore, I guess :D

Comment: I just tried to adapt this to my main Problem, but now i have no type restrictions for the Component. Is it possible to restrict that in the bottom Solution ?

Comment: @Cascade_Ho could you please provide me with example, I mean where exact you have a problem with type restrictions?

Comment: When i call the function with ```<Generic Component={...}``` I can pass any possible Object inside the Component. But i want it to be restricted only to either ObjA or ObjB. In the real case its an Array of similar Objects with the size of n  
The thing i was starting with are Survey Components, as shown in the linked Question. I want to constrain the Component to be one of those

Comment: @Cascade_Ho than you need to use curried version. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/wQ5Yvw). Here we have a problem with component type. It is a function with contravariant arguments. TS does not like it